# How to save, load and edit lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, save, local-storage, edit

So I have heard about saving and I wanted to make so that on my website users can make list of clickable links and save them and delete them. So is it possible? I am good at HTML and CSS but I am just learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible. You need to save the data somewhere : it could be on the browser of the user by using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or on the server by creating an API that can save the data, for example, in a database.

or use Simple NodeJs Express [example app url](https://medium.com/@atingenkay/creating-a-todo-app-with-node-js-express-8fa51f39b16f)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list of links in an array and then `JSON.stringify` it so you can store it in `localStorage` (`localStorage` only accepts strings). Just have an input for links and a button to add them then add some event listeners to read then change `localStorage`.

Comment: But I am very bad at JavaScript

Comment: @NPCFISH well then you can learn by reading docs and other online resources.